# How do I deprecate a feature in my addon?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-3

I am writing an Ember.js Addon, and I need to deprecate a feature. Can I use the same deprecation system that Ember uses? 
I want my users to be able to silence the warnings.

Ideally, I also need to be able to test that the deprecation message works under the right conditions, from within my test suite.

I'm using Ember 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

An addon can use the same style of deprecation warnings as Ember uses, through the [`deprecate`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fapplication%2Fdeprecations/deprecate) method:

```js
import { deprecate } from '@ember/application/deprecations';
```

`deprecate` takes three arguments: the string as a message, a boolean test where falsey means the deprecation will be shown, and an options object with more information to be displayed.

For example:

```js
import { deprecate } from '@ember/application/deprecations';
// ...
deprecate(
   "message about your addon that mentions the addon by name", 
   false,
   {
      id: 'send-component-hash',
      until: '2.0.0',
      url: 'some url goes here'
    }
);
// ...
```

The message in the console will look something like this:

[image: a yellow warning box with an alert icon and instructions]

Testing a deprecation can be done with a library like [ember-qunit-assert](https://github.com/workmanw/ember-qunit-assert-helpers#emberdeprecate-assertions). Once it is installed, `expectDeprecation` will be available on `assert` if you are already using `qunit` in your tests:

```
assert.expectDeprecation(/expected deprecation message/);
```

Comment: If it's only about renaming an attribute, event or function [`deprecatingAlias` macro](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/deprecatingAlias) is also very helpful.

Comment: Thanks @jelhan, I'll add that suggestion to the documentation I just wrote!